# Delete Stored Procedure not finding Id in Editable GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a fairly simple stored procedure that drops an Id when the Administrator does not need it. I use it on the front end of my web app.

This is the T-SQL:

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGRNTSFunderId_Delete]
@FunderId int = NULL 
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DELETE FROM tblGRNTSFunders WHERE ([FunderId] = @FunderId AND @FunderId IS NOT NULL) END
```

I am only trying to use the front-end to call this form a Button within the GridView as this is how I've done it on the other pages.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbtnDelete" CommandName="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
```

The delete is in the SDS declaration.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsFunders_Page" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseLive %>"
        SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
        SelectCommand="spGRNTSFunders_Select"
        DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure"
        DeleteCommand="spGRNTSFunders_Delete">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="FunderId" QueryStringField="FunderId" Type="Int32" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
        </SelectParameters></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Checking the SQL Profiler, the command that executes on Delete is exec `spFunderId_Delete` but no `@FunderId` is called. It is supposed to be `spFunderId_Delete @FunderId=someId`

I tried coding it but it also does not work. It finds the Id though.. This is what I tried.

```
protected void gvFunders_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    string procedureDelete = "spGRNTSFunders_Delete";

    int index = gvFunders.EditIndex;
    GridViewRow row = gvFunders.Rows[index];

    // find wp ID
    Label lblFunderId = (Label)row.FindControl("lblFunderId");
    string FunderId = lblFunderId.Text;

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = procedureDelete;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FunderId", FunderId);
    gvFunders_WP.DataBind();

}
```

What are your thoughts?

Comment: You appear to have another parameter also: `@WFunderId`. And the code you wrote isn't going to do anything because you aren't doing anything with the command after you create it. I would imagine if you added `DeleteParameters` to the XAML it might just work though

Comment: @Charlieface the LinkButton has a CommandName="Delete" which has to invoke DeleteCommand="spGRNTSFunders_Delete" from the SQLDataSource. This is how I usually do it on my other pages where I delete a PersonId for exampe. The WFunderId is FunderId, just a typo when copy pasting. The parameter FunderId is inside an ItemTemplate on the Editable Grid, so clicking on Edit usually grabs the FunderId. The stored procedure for Saving and selecting works perfectly fine, its the Delete that is misbehaving. It has to be the front-end though.

Comment: But have you tried adding `DeleteParameters` as [shown in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.deleteparameters?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: @Charlieface actually there is an improvement if I use  <asp:Parameter Name="FunderId" Type="Int32" /> within DeleteParameters as now the profiler shows "exec spGRNTSFunders_Delete @FunderId=NULL, so all I have to do is locate it.

Comment: Yeah you need `QueryStringField="FunderId"` or something like that

Comment: Essentially it will become <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="FudnerId" QueryStringField="lblFunderId" Type="Int32"  />. I think we are really close to the answer, but it is still executing the sp with Id=NULL